# Facebook gallery/lightbox - centred image while loading

Tags: javascript, css, facebook

Does Facebook in its gallery put image width and height in database?

Using JavaScript, they can not be sure about image width and height until image fully loads. But on FB, image is been loaded while its displaying and image is properly centered horizontally and vertically.

Comment: I'm too lazy to go look at FB right now, so I'll make a comment instead of an answer.... You can center horizontally with margin:auto if the container has text-align:center, and you can use padding to force a visual vertical centering.

Comment: Ok, for the horizontally, but it is not possible to center it vertically for every instance of a different image?

Comment: Facebook already knows the exact width & height because _they_ resized the image to _their_ specifications after the user uploaded it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook use `display:inline-block` for the image and `text-align:center` for parent div to center image in theater images.
Check out their [blog post](http://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/developing-facebooks-new-photo-viewer/499447633919) that explained how they did it. It's a nice CSS code but not all CSS. They use JS to set `line-height` of one of divs based on `window.height`.

Comment: How did they create those `div`-s and set on `body` `overflow:hidden` without JS?